# Redshift : Copy command failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, copy, amazon-redshift

While loading the data into Redshift from S3 using the copy command, I am getting the below error:
Undoing 1 transactions on table 456834 with current xid 9286221: 9286221
I tried changing the copy command with various options but no luck.
I checked the console and found that even COPY ANALYZE is failing.
I spent a lot of time on it but couldn't find a way to solve the issue. Any help would be highly appreiciated.

Thanks,
S

Comment: pls post the copy command your are trying and sample records from your file, if you could.

Comment: How are you sending commands to Redshift? The mention of Transactions suggests that your are using an SQL client that does not have auto-commit activated, and an earlier error might be rejecting all future commands until there is a roll-back.